# How can I access my user object from loginLocals using everyauth?

Tags: node.js, everyauth

I have tried the following

```
.loginLocals(function (req, res, done) {
    console.log(req.user);
    done();

})
```

And it seems to be called upon GET (req.user is undefined) but not POST (at which point I would be able to access the user and feed in related parameters)